# Использование parseInt

Tags: java, парсер

Имеется пример кода на js:

```
<script>
var a = parseInt(prompt(A)) 
if(a == 0)
    {
        alert("A равно 0");
    }
    else if(a > 0)
    {
        alert("A положительное");
    }
    else if(a < 0)
    {
        alert("A отрицательное");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("похоже Вы ввели число");
    }
</script>
```

хочу сделать тоже самое на java:

```
public class Pr1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("введите число");
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scr.nextInt();

    if(n == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("N равно 0");
    }
    else if(n > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("N положительное");
    }
    else if(n < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("N отрицательное");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели буквы");
    }
}
}
```

Вопрос: как в простом варианте (без использования while, for, do-while, т.к. этот материал еще не затрагивался - уместить в 1, 2 или 3 строчки код) используя parseInt, чтобы при вводе символов не выходила ошибка и на выходе было “Вы ввели буквы”?

Answer (score 0):

**Упростить можно только так. По - другому никак!**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("введите число");
            Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(n == 0 ? "N равно 0" : n > 0
                    ? "N положительное" : "N отрицательное");
        } catch (InputMismatchException x) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели буквы");
        }
    }
}
```